# RSpec stub current_user in controller

Tags: ruby, rspec

Currently I am writing some controller test with rspec. The controller requires user to sign in before being usable.

if @current_user.nil?
 do something
else 
 redirect

I currently have issues on how to stub the local variable current_user.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have rspec login to your test system rather than stubbing current_user.  You could do something like the following:

```
  describe "Req #5 - login" do
    it 'loads the login page' do
      get '/login'
      expect(last_response.status).to eq(200)
    end

    it 'loads the user index after login' do
      user = User.create(:username => "Raptor", :password => "Raptor")
      params = {
        :username => "Raptor",
        :password => "Raptor"
      }
      post '/login', params
      follow_redirect!
      expect(last_response.body).to include("Home Page for: Raptor")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Could I do that with a non user controller?

Comment: You could definitely have rspec login and then drive tests through various other controllers.

Comment: This approach is considerably slower than stubbing the `controller#current_user`.

Answer (score 0):

You can stub the controller's current_user method like this:

```
let(:current_user) { User.create(...) }

before do
  allow(@controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(current_user)
end
```